# ERROR [HY000] [Microsoft] The specified field 'ono' could refer to more than one table listed in the FROM clause of your SQL statement

Tags: c#, vb.net, winforms, datagridview, textbox

There are two tables cscorder & cscorder_item. 'cscorder' has field "ono,tno,tname,tdate,amt' & 'cscorder_item' has field "ono,name,age,sex". I want to concatenate these two tables and display following details in a datagridview. So i used command:

```
"select a.ono,a.tno,a.tname,a.tdate,a.amount,b.name,b.age,b.sex from cscorder a,cscorder_item b where ono=" + textBox6.Text + "";
```

However, it shows error 'The specified field 'ono' could refer to more than one table'.
Please suggest me a proper command for it. Any help will be appreciated. I have not much knowledge about it. So try to explain as simply as possible.

Comment: This is a [sql injection attack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) waiting to happen. What if I enter "1; DROP DATABASE;" in textBox6.Text? [Little Bobby Tables](http://xkcd.com/327/) would be proud :)

Comment: The error message does try to explain it in very simple language. Your query involves more than one table. Both of those tables, apparently, contain a column called `ono`. You where clause says `where ono=...` and the system doesn't know which table's `ono` to use.

Answer (score 0):

@Damien_The_Unbeliever explained a error message's reason in comments.
For getting result of only one value of `ono`(Order number i assume), you need to join two tables by `ono` value. [About Joins in SQL](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/04/13/sql-server-introduction-to-joins-basic-of-joins/)
Try this query:

```
Dim query as New StringBuilder()
With query
    .AppendLine("SELECT ord.ono AS OrderOno")
    .AppendLine(", ord.tno")
    .AppendLine(", ord.tname")
    .AppendLine(", ord.tdate")
    .AppendLine(", ord.amount")
    .AppendLine(", itm.name")
    .AppendLine(", itm.age")
    .AppendLine(", itm.sex")
    .AppendLine("FROM cscorder ord")
    .AppendLine("LEFT JOIN cscorder_item itm ON itm.ono = ord.ono")
    .Append("WHERE ord.ono = ")
    .AppendLine(textBox6.Text)
End With
```

But seriously consider about using `SqlParameter` in your queries. It helps in many things, not only sql injection. Some examples of using parameters:
[From MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter(v=vs.110).aspx)
[From Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19789562/create-data-sqlclient-sqlparameter-with-a-sqldatatype-size-and-value-inline)

Answer (score -2):

```
string query = string.Format("select a.ono,a.tno,a.tname,a.tdate,a.amount,b.name,b.age,b.sex from cscorder a,cscorder_item b where a.ono={0}",textBox6.Text);
```

give query string as your query.

Comment: That will probably work but it's not very safe. You should consider using a parameterized query.

Comment: i had tried these things..bt when i do so it display only the terms related to ono of table a. but join all the data of table b.

Comment: i need command to display only the data related with that particular ono from both the tables.

Comment: @SauravArya That is what your current query is asking for, otherwise you need to use an inner join (or maybe a left join)

Comment: my requirement is to display all data related with given ono from both tables.